# How can I left join a subquery in hibernate with criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to be able to left join a subquery in hibernate with criteria.

Here is sample query:

```
Select * From Order o
Left Join (Select * From Product p Where p.accountId = 3) p
On p.id = o.productId
Where (p.category is not null and p.category = 'clothes') or 
(p.category is null and o.category = 'clothes')
```

Note this is a sample query, mine is more complex and I need to be able to left join a subquery.

### How could you generate this query with the hibernate criteria syntax?

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);

DetachedCriteria productCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Product.class);
productCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("accountId", 3));

criteria.createAlias("productCriteria", "p", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, productCriteria);

criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
        Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNotNull("p.category"), Restrictions.eq("p.category", "clothes")),
   Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("p.category"), Restrictions.eq("category", "clothes"))
));

List list = criteria.list();
```

### Edit

In my real problem the subquery consists of two tables.

Comment: What hibernate version?

Comment: Regardless of the hibernate version, you would have to map the relation in your entity model i.e. the `Order` entity needs a one-to-many relation to `Product`. You can use hibernates `WITH` clause for the restriction on the `accountId` like `FROM Order o LEFT JOIN o.products p WITH p.accountId = 3`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I have that and also I am able to do with `p.accountId = 3`. However if the subquery contains a join, that does not work. I have solved this with a in clause... But I would like to know if this is possible...

Comment: Hibernate does not support subqueries in the FROM clause if that is what you want to know. You can almost always reformulate the subquery to a relation join, but you'd have to adapt the model for that. You shouldn't use the Hibernate Criteria API anymore as it got deprecated in 5 and might be removed in 6.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov Yes I want to use it in the FROM clause. It will simplify my query a lot. But thank you for the answer and the information. I just adjusted my query without the FROM clause...

Answer (score 1):

You can use createAlias API of Criteria class and specify join type.
Refer [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int)) documentation for more details.

```
    Criteria createAlias(String associationPath,
                 String alias,
                 int joinType)
                 throws HibernateException
Join an association using the specified join-type, assigning an alias to the joined association.
The joinType is expected to be one of CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN (the default), CriteriaSpecification.FULL_JOIN, or CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN.
```

Comment: This will do a left join, but what about the subquery part? createAlias takes a parameter criterion but not a Criteria...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `Criteria` method to use subquery in joins.

```
public Criteria createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, JoinType joinType, Criterion withClause) throws HibernateException;
```

and a `Criterion` parameter, which you can create with the `Subqueries` factory class, will generate a subquery in the join condition.

You will end up with something like this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order.class);

DetachedCriteria productCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Product.class)
                .setProjection(property("id"))
                .add(Restrictions.eq("accountId", 3));

criteria.createAlias("product", "p", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Subqueries.propertyEq("id", productCriteria));
...
```